# How to sum certain columns row-by-row in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this (with values for all Threads as the frame progresses):

```
head(icdata)
     Count Thread1 Thread2 Thread3 Thread4 Thread5 Thread6 Thread7 Thread8 
1  8543034  555724      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2 26632195  730156      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3 46332821  730679      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
4 47491531   22694   16715      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
5 48939781   62418  114842      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
6 50397031   63560   38147      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

I'd like to plot Count against the sum of the various threads, but cannot work out just how to do it - eg the NA values seem to cause me problems in just summing the row. Sorry to ask such a basic question but how can I do this?

(Additionally, I'd like to be able to normalise this total against the difference in the Counts, but that is less essential)

Comment: Have a close look at `?sum`, paying particular attention to its description of the function's `na.rm` argument. Then do something like `cbind(df[1], Threadsum=apply(df[-1], 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: Josh, please make that an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like nico's answer is just as acceptable. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rowSums` to sum the values in the various threads. The `na.rm` parameters takes care of NAs. Furthermore, you want to exclude the first column from the sum so:

```
thread.sum <- rowSums(icdata[,-1], na.rm=TRUE)
plot(icdata[,1], thread.sum)
```